# How do I animate on hover or timeout with jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

So I want to animate and display a menu on an element hover or when certain time has passed without a hover.

This I what I've got but it doesn't work.

```
var didAnimationStart = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#logoi').hover(startAnimation()); 
    var t = setTimeout("if (didAnimationStart==0) startAnimation();",10000);
});

function startAnimation()
{
        didAnimationStart = 1;
        $('.linea').animate({
            width: "93%",
        }, 3000 );
        $('.menu-txt').animate({
            opacity: "1",
        }, 2500 );  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You can chekout the end product here: http://labelshowroom.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var didAnimationStart = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#logoi').hover(startAnimation); 
    var t = setTimeout(function() { 
        if (didAnimationStart==0) startAnimation();
    },10000);
});

function startAnimation()
{
        didAnimationStart = 1;
        $('.linea').animate({
            width: "93%",
        }, 3000 );
        $('.menu-txt').animate({
            opacity: "1",
        }, 2500 );  
}
```

I got rid of the `()` in this line: `$('#logoi').hover(startAnimation);`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But why dont we call a function with the whole function name+parameters like "startAnimation()"?

Comment: @Agush: because then instead of setting it to run the function each time, you're saying run it now once and assign it the return value of the function